# Wiremock proxy record feature - can it replace Host or IP in responses?

Tags: java, wiremock

I am recording rest api's with wiremock... in my case for SharePoint.

So I set up a recorder:

`java -jar wiremock-standalone-2.18.0.jar`

Now I go to http://localhost:8080/__admin/recorder/ and I enable recording for my http://sharepointhost.

Now I make some requests to sharepoint rest apis through http://localhost:8080.

But the rest api responses still reference the http://sharepointhost.

Is there a way to turn on some sort of reverse proxy or URL pattern string replace so I can avoid this issue? What is the way to do that in my case? Do I need to use the Java variety of the recorder instead of using the standalone?

Comment: Can you explain where the URL's are found in the response? Is it the header, the body of the message or elsewhere?

Comment: body of the message.... but maybe in other places too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WireMock supports "Extensions." And there are some pre-packaged extension types called "Transformers."

There is an extension type that allows you to intercept responses of http requests. Here you can then replace contents of responses.

See http://wiremock.org/docs/extending-wiremock/

I created a GitHub repository with a response body URL rewrite extension:

https://github.com/nddipiazza/wiremock-response-body-url-rewriter

```
public class ResponseBodyUrlRewriteTransformer extends ResponseTransformer {

  final int wiremockPort;
  final String wiremockBindAddress;
  final private List<String> urlsToReplace;

  public ResponseBodyUrlRewriteTransformer(String wiremockBindAddress, int wiremockPort, List<String> urlsToReplace) {
    this.urlsToReplace = urlsToReplace;
    this.wiremockBindAddress = wiremockBindAddress;
    this.wiremockPort = wiremockPort;
  }

  private String replaceUrlsInBody(String bodyText) {
    for (String urlToReplace : urlsToReplace) {
      bodyText = bodyText.replaceAll(Pattern.quote(urlToReplace),
          "http://" + wiremockBindAddress + ":" + wiremockPort);
    }
    return bodyText;
  }

  @Override
  public Response transform(Request request, Response response, FileSource files, Parameters parameters) {
    if (response.getStatus() == 200) {
      ContentTypeHeader contentTypeHeader = response.getHeaders().getContentTypeHeader();
      if (contentTypeHeader != null && contentTypeHeader.mimeTypePart().contains("xml")) {
        return Response.response()
            .body(replaceUrlsInBody(response.getBodyAsString()))
            .headers(response.getHeaders())
            .status(response.getStatus())
            .statusMessage(response.getStatusMessage())
            .fault(response.getFault())
            .chunkedDribbleDelay(response.getChunkedDribbleDelay())
            .fromProxy(response.isFromProxy())
            .build();
      }
    }
    return response;
  }

  @Override
  public String getName() {
    return "ResponseBodyUrlRewriteTransformer";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can launch WireMock as a proxy with automatic record mode. The command you need is this:

java -jar wiremock-standalone-2.18.0.jar --port 8787 --print-all-network-traffic --verbose  --enable-browser-proxying  --record-mappings

The important params there are **enable-browser-proxying** and **record-mappings**

The proxy is running on port 8787 and you have to configure your browser to use proxy localhost:8787

Now you can browse any web site, and all the trafic will be recorded.

Comment: Nope this does nothing. You possibly didn't read my question closely enough. The problem is that the responses continue to have the original hostname not the proxy hostname. So in my use case, this breaks my program because it uses the URLs in a certain way. I want my wiremock to replace all the actual urls with the proxy url replacement